# GUI Program Calculation #2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am supposed to write a program with check buttons that allow the user to select any or all of these services. When the user clicks a button the total charges should be displayed. I already have the first portion done and finished but I need help with the second part. I can't find a calculation that works when the user clicks the buttons and the total charges are calculated and displayed within the same box. What is the correct calculation to add the selected? Here's what I have so far:

```
#Create the checkbutton widgets in top frame.

        self.cb1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, \
                    text = 'Oil Change-$30.00', variable = self.cb_var1)
        self.cb2 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, \
                    text = 'Lube Job-$20.00', variable = self.cb_var2)
        self.cb3 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, \
                    text = 'Radiator Flush-$40.00', variable = self.cb_var3)
        self.cb4 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, \
                    text = 'Transmission Flush-$100.00', variable = self.cb_var4)
        self.cb5 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, \
                    text = 'Inspection-$35.00', variable = self.cb_var5)
        self.cb6 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, \
                    text = 'Muffler Replacement-$200.00', variable = self.cb_var6)
        self.cb7 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, \
                    text = 'Tire Rotation-$20.00', variable = self.cb_var7)

#Pack the checkbuttons.

        self.cb1.pack()
        self.cb2.pack()
        self.cb3.pack()
        self.cb4.pack()
        self.cb5.pack()
        self.cb6.pack()
        self.cb7.pack()

#Create an OK button and Quit button.

        self.ok_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, \
                    text = 'OK', command = self.show_choice)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, \
                    text = 'Quit', command = self.main_window.destroy)

#Pack the buttons.

        self.ok_button.pack(side = 'left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side = 'left')

#Pack frame.

        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()
```

Comment: By default `Checkbuttons` put a value of `0` or `1` into their associated `IntVar`. This means you'll need to check all 7 of them by calling `self.cb_varX.get()` on each and if the value is not zero (or `False`) add the corresponding charge to a running total that is also being kept.

Comment: What would that look like in code? (Sorry, I'm a visual learner)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a tkinter person but I would do it as if I was making this in wxpython and you will just have to translate it from there.

So first I would make a dictionary of all checkbox names and the price associated with it. It would look something like this:

```
priceCheckUp = {"Oil Change-$30.00":30, "Lube Job-$20.00":20...} #Keep going with all the rest of them
```

Next you would want list of all the checkboxes. I would change your code to have your checkboxes appended to a list like:

```
checkboxes = []
checkboxes.append(tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, \
                    text = 'Oil Change-$30.00', variable = self.cb_var1)) #Do that for all of them
```

So now that you have a list, you can use a for loop like such after the user presses the button:

```
total = 0
for i in checkboxes:
   if i.isChecked():
      total = total + priceCheckUp[i.GetLabel()]
print total #Or display the data however you want
```

The above code was done for wxPython Checkboxes so you will have to do some translating.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of the essence of what I said in my comment. Although it's based on the code in your answer, I've added a lot of supporting code so I could test it. One significant change I made was to put all the Checkbutton widgets and their associated control variables into lists instead of explicitly giving each one a unique name — which was getting out-of-hand you have so many of them.

That said, the checking of the state of each Checkbutton and adding up the costs of checked items in shown in the `show_choice()` method.

```
import tkinter

# Table of services containing their names and costs.
SERVICES = [('Oil Change', 30.00),
            ('Lube Job', 20.00),
            ('Radiator Flush', 40.00),
            ('Transmission Flush', 100.00),
            ('Inspection', 35.00),
            ('Muffler Replacement', 200.00),
            ('Tire Rotation', 20.00)]

class MyApp(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        self.main_window = root
        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame(self)
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame(self)

        # Create list of control variables to query state of CheckButtons.
        self.cb_vars = [tkinter.IntVar() for _ in range(len(SERVICES))]

        # Create another list to hold a corresponding Checkbuttons.
        self.cbs = [
            tkinter.Checkbutton(
                self.top_frame,
                text='{}-${:.2f}'.format(SERVICES[i][0], SERVICES[i][1]),
                variable=self.cb_vars[i])
            for i in range(len(self.cb_vars))
        ]
        # Pack the Checkbuttons.
        for i in range(len(self.cbs)):
            self.cbs[i].pack()

        #Create an OK button and Quit button.
        self.ok_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,
                    text='OK', command=self.show_choice)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,
                    text='Quit', command=self.main_window.destroy)

        #Pack the buttons.
        self.ok_button.pack(side = 'left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side = 'left')

        #Pack frames.
        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

    def show_choice(self):
        popup_window = tkinter.Toplevel()
        label_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(popup_window, text='Total Charges')
        label_frame.pack()
        # Add up the cost of all the items which are checked.
        total = sum(SERVICES[i][1] for i in range(len(self.cb_vars))
                        if self.cb_vars[i].get())
        tkinter.Label(label_frame, text='${:.2f}'.format(total)).pack()
        # Enter a local mainloop and wait for window to be closed by user.
        root.wait_window(popup_window)

root = tkinter.Tk()
app = MyApp(root)
app.master.title('Cost Calculator')
app.mainloop()
```

Here's a screenshot of it running:

[image: screenshot of code running]